# Local sightseeing in Sao Paulo on a budget - in a day, solo traveler - is it doable?

Tags: budget, sightseeing, brazil, solo-travel, sao-paulo

I will have a **Saturday evening** and a **full Sunday** for local sight-seeing in Sao Paulo.  A few characteristics of my 1.5 days available in **Sao Paulo** being:

- Solo traveler, will be staying quite close to the central business area
- Do not know Portuguese (read, speak or write), so left to English alone
- Don't mind walking, using metro or local buses
- Will have Google-maps with offline map of city available on my phone with GPS 'on'

Not interested in shopping malls, but definitely like seeing local traditional marketplace, good architecture, local art, culture, historic monuments or places of historic significance, anything unique about the place.

Given the above, can I imagine planning sightseeing without spending a lot of money? Idea is to spend quality time at a leisurely pace, and not necessarily cover every possible touristy spot!

Comment: If you are happy walking, and don't want to go shopping, then you can visit practically anywhere on a budget.

Comment: True, but Sao Paulo is rather stretched out to make this really viable in the space of a day and a half. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

Although the right answer is very dependent on your personal interests, here are a few pointers to get you started:

- Do a ['free' walking tour](http://www.saopaulofreewalkingtour.com/). They work for tips, so it's not really free, but it's an easy and friendly way to get to know a bit of the city.
- Spend time at [Ibirapuera Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibirapuera_Park). There are several decent museums in the park, and it's a great place to relax and watch the world go by.
- Spend an afternoon or evening exploring [Vila Madelana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vila_Madalena), a lovely suburb full of restaurants and bars.

Comment: Thank you. Definitely don't mind tipping. So, would be good to know usual tipping practices and amount. Should I start a separate question for it ?

Comment: Nah. At the start of the tour, they'll explain that it's free, but that they work for tips. They'll mention a typical tipping amount for when you're happy with the tour. Typically (tipically?), they'll suggest an amount that's a tad high, and it's completely up to you, anyway. My rule of thumb for 'free' tours is that, if I liked the tour, I'll tip roughly the equivalent of a museum visit.